# Knockout subscribe executing multiple times

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

So i've been knocking my head on this for quite a while now and i just can't seem to figure it out (i'm not very good at javascript). We have a modal which has the following 2 fields:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: UnitCost" maxlength="256" style="width: 75px;" />
<input type="text" data-bind="value: ExtendedUnitCost" maxlength="256" style="width: 75px;" />
```

which has the following 2 subscribe fields

```
InfoModel.ExtendedUnitCost.subscribe(function (val) {
    console.log("1 quantity " + InfoModel.Quantity() + " value "+ val);
    if (typeof val !== 'undefined') {
        var Cost = parseFloat(val.toString().replace(',', '.')) / InfoModel.Quantity();

        InfoModel.UnitCost(Cost.toFixed(2));
    }
});

InfoModel.UnitCost.subscribe(function (val) {
    console.log("2 quantity " + InfoModel.Quantity() + " value " + val);
    if (typeof val !== 'undefined') {
        var unitCostExtended = parseFloat(val.toString().replace(',', '.')) * InfoModel.Quantity();
        InfoModel.ExtendedUnitCost(unitCostExtended.toFixed(2));
    }
});
```

Now when i set the Quantity to 10 and the Unitcost to 10. The extended unit cost is as expected 100. When i now change the quantity to 8. I see the following in the Log outputs.

1. 2 quantity 8 value 10
2. 1 quantity 8 value 80.00
3. 2 quantity 8 value 10.00
4. 1 quantity 8 value 100
5. 2 quantity 8 value 12.50
6. 1 quantity 8 value 100.00

Here, 1 and 2 are correct, 3 is correct but 4 is incorrect and 5 & 6 are incorrect. When changing the quantity i would expect the Extended to be adjusted (as it is in the first run) but in the next run it adjusts the extended amount.

Answer (score 0):

Why these are correct: ????

quantity 8 value 10

quantity 8 value 80.00

quantity 8 value 10.00

Why these are incorrect: ????

quantity 8 value 100

8 value 12.50

quantity 8 value 100.00

What is the formula???

**UPDATE:**

First of all, if you do not need to update UnitCost - Do not do it!
So, **remove** this code:

```
InfoModel.ExtendedUnitCost.subscribe(function (val) {
    console.log("quantity " + InfoModel.Quantity() + " value "+ val);
    if (typeof val !== 'undefined') {
        var Cost = parseFloat(val.toString().replace(',', '.')) / InfoModel.Quantity();

        InfoModel.UnitCost(Cost.toFixed(2));
    }
});
```

and see what happens now?

Comment: unitCost * Quantity = extended amount. So With a unit cost of 10 and a quantity of 8 the extended should be 80, not 100. And the unit cost should not change to 12.50 to keep the extended cost at 100.

Comment: And where is the quantity field?

Comment: The data is in InfoModel.Quantity(). Its in a different view.

Comment: Remove the code that updates your UnitCost and see what happens then. (See in my updated answer).

Comment: Then it  still wont update the Extended Cost. However during data entry it is also possible that they add the extended cost from which the unit cost then needs to be calculated. So this code is also needed.

Comment: Then You have a logic problem. The code should UnitCost should be updated on ExtendedCost change or no? If yes - then keep the code, if no - then remove. If the ExtendedCost is not updated on the UnitCost change - try debugging the model.